# Передать функции 3 указателя на массивы и изменить их

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Есть 3 массива типа `double`. Передаю их в функцию через указатель, выделяю под них новый размер, инициализирую. Но после выхода из функции, сами массивы не изменяются в итоге. В чем ошибка?

```
double *open = new double[LIST_SIZE];
double *high = new double[LIST_SIZE];
double *low = new double[LIST_SIZE];
double *close = new double[LIST_SIZE];
double *volume = new double[LIST_SIZE];
CompressTo(open, high, low, close, volume, date, count, 5);


void CompressTo(double* open, double* high, double* low, double* close, double* volume, Date* date, int &count, int TF)
{
vector<double> newOpen, newHigh, newLow, newClose, newVolume;
vector<Date> newDate;
//Здесь я добавляю в вектора какие-то значения, размер у всех векторов одинаковый.
count = newOpen.size();

open = new double[count];
high = new double[count];
low = new double[count];
close = new double[count];
volume = new double[count];
date = new Date[count];
copy(newOpen.begin(), newOpen.end(), open);
copy(newHigh.begin(), newHigh.end(), high);
copy(newLow.begin(), newLow.end(), low);
copy(newClose.begin(), newClose.end(), close);
copy(newVolume.begin(), newVolume.end(), volume);
copy(newDate.begin(), newDate.end(), date);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию **значения** указателей `open` и иже с ними. В функции вы присваиваете значения **локальным** переменным, которые определены только в функции, и не имеют никакого отношения к переменным вне - кроме того, что их начальное значение берется из внешних переменных.

По выходу из функции значения `open` и прочих *внутри функции* просто теряются.

Так что к вашим неприятностям добавляется еще и утечка памяти.

Вы работаете в C++? Передавайте по ссылке (`void CompressTo(double* &open...`). Но у вас это далеко не единственная и не самая большая ошибка...

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал, что можно писать таким образом передачу параметров `double* &open`. Совмещая указатель и ссылку. На счет утечки памяти, я понимаю, буду потом отлаживать весь код и удалять временную память.

Comment: Возвращали бы сразу вектора из функции, без махинаций с массивами. Уметь нужно конечно с массивами обращаться , но тут столько лишних телодвижений.

Comment: А вереница из массивов double* open, double* high, double* low, double* close, double* volume так и напрашивается сложить их в одну структуру.

Comment: @JaponDemon Это да, но тогда уже в класс со своими методами :) Но это уже другой вопрос - по рефакторингу...

Comment: @Harry, ну поворчать же надо немножко... )

Comment: @JaponDemon я просто использую далее технологию OpenCL и туда лучше переносить все массивы отдельно, чем в структуре.

Comment: @JaponDemon также в OpenCL нету  vector`ов. А как мне в c++ использовать динамический массив, если я не знаю количество элементов.. Поэтому и использую вначале вектор, а потом в массив переделываю.